# Angular Binding with JQuery Event Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, class, binding

I have a list of links where clicking on each one of them updates the selectedLinkIndex value with a unique numeric index. If a link's index (refer to the ng-click binding in JS fiddle below) is equal to selectedLinkIndex then the link's class is updated to colour it red with CSS.

I want to extend this functionality so that pressing the left and right arrow keys increments/decrements the selectedLinkIndex and updates the links' classes to colour the selected link red (according to the aforementioned behaviour).

However, this does not seem to work (refer to my [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sapiens_fio/1ravkdvL/2/)). Why doesn't this work and how can I implement the desired behaviour?

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" id="link1" ng-class="linkClass(0)" ng-click="updateLinkIndex(0)">Link1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="link2" ng-class="linkClass(1)" ng-click="updateLinkIndex(1)">Link2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="link3" ng-class="linkClass(2)" ng-click="updateLinkIndex(2)">Link3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectedLinkIndex = 0;
    $scope.linkClass = function(index) {
        return (index == $scope.selectedLinkIndex) ? "active" : "";
    }

    $scope.updateLinkIndex = function(value) {
        $scope.selectedLinkIndex = value;
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        switch(e.which) {
            case 37:
                $scope.selectedLinkIndex--;
                break;
            case 39:
                $scope.selectedLinkIndex++;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        alert("Selected Link index is now " + $scope.selectedLinkIndex);
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell to your view what you want to be revalued.

In angular, you can find 2 methods :

- `$digest`
- `$apply`

`$digest()` will only fire watchers on your current scope, instead of `$apply` which whill evaluate a function and run `$rootScope.$digest()`.

In other word, when you call `$apply`, you will evaluate the `$rootScope` and the child scopes.

If you call `$digest`, you will evaluate watchers for current scope, so it's faster.

A call to `$apply()` will force a `$digest()`.

[Scope documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

So, in your case, you can call a `$digest()` when a key is pressed :

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.selectedLinkIndex = 0;
    $scope.linkClass = function(index) {
        return (index == $scope.selectedLinkIndex) ? "active" : "";
    }

    $scope.updateLinkIndex = function(value) {
        $scope.selectedLinkIndex = value;
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
       switch(e.which) {
            case 37:
                $scope.selectedLinkIndex--;
                break;
            case 39:
                $scope.selectedLinkIndex++;
                break;
            default:
                return;
        }
        //Call $digest cycle
        $scope.$digest();
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to update your `angular.js` file to the latest one `@1.4.3`, i would suggest you to update your code like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl); // <---define the controller here.

function MyCtrl($scope, $timeout) { // use a $timeout svc to run the digest
    console.log($scope);            // cycle to update the values.
    $scope.selectedLinkIndex = 0;
    $scope.linkClass = function(index) {
        return (index == $scope.selectedLinkIndex) ? "active" : "";
    }

    $scope.updateLinkIndex = function(value) {
        $scope.selectedLinkIndex = value;
    }

    $(document).keydown(function(e) {
        $timeout(function(){ // wrap this code inside $timeout
          switch(e.which) {
            case 37:
                $scope.linkClass($scope.selectedLinkIndex--); // call the linkClass method and update the index
                break;
            case 39:
                $scope.linkClass($scope.selectedLinkIndex++);// call the linkClass method and update the index
                break;
            default:
                return;
          }
        },0);

        alert("Selected Link index is now " + $scope.selectedLinkIndex);
    });    
}
```

#### [Updated fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/1ravkdvL/3/)